# script error on linux ubuntu /bin/sh: curl: not found?

Tags: linux, magento, ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to run this script from the cron job schedule on Ubuntu Linux 10.04.1 server but i get the following out put:

[image]

Curl seems to be enabled on the serevr this is the extract fro the phpinfo file:
[image]

The cron script is to clean the log files in a magento db

I have tried various things but just can't get the thing to work ? any ideas would be a great help thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You mixed up the curl php-module and the system executable.

Connect to a shell and enter the following:

```sh
sudo apt-get install curl
```

If you don't want to install `curl` try to use `wget`.

Answer (score 2):

You have **curl extension** for php installed. But **NOT** curl command line client.

As you are using Ubuntu install it by,

```
sudo aptitude install curl
```

After that in the cron tab use full path of the curl
Like

```
/usr/bin/curl
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the phpinfo() exceprt only tells you, that php is compiled with libcurl support and can use the curl functions. Try checking if curl is actually installed (the binary). If not install it and modify your cron-script to use thee full path (ususally `/usr/bin/curl`) of the command.